# Rich link preview works on Facebook but not on WhatsApp

Tags: html, facebook, hyperlink, whatsapp, preview

I am doing a website that is supposed to be 'previewed on WhatsApp' if you write the link in the chat. I have applied the needed tags and it still does not work but it does preview on Facebook.

Here are the tags inserted inside the head:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Titlehere</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="name"/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="mywebsite.ga"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Décorez votre maison!">
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://mywebsitehere.ga"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content=imglink goes here/>


        <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is what i get on Facebook:

[image]

I have no idea why it does not work on WhatsApp please if i am doing anything wrong let me know.

Comment: i have the same problem , any solution ?